# One-liner to XOR two strings?

Tags: linux, bash, security, encryption

I have a message in base36 (ie: [a-z0-9]+) and I want to XOR it with a base36 key. Is this possible? What's the easiest way to do that? Can it be done with a one-liner on linux?

Comment: Can you give an example of an input/output combination?

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper .... :( didnt understand the question .... could you  give some more info on what you are doing , sounds interesting !!

Comment: @NSD I'm trying to encrypt something with one-time pad, which is very interesting indeed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper , thanks ..... didnt know of that , +1  and nice stuff. I will try to do that too :)

Answer (score 4):

Xoring with perl on the command line

example xor encode

```
perl -e '$a="abc"; $k="flock"; use MIME::Base64; print encode_base64($a ^ $k)'
Bw4MY2s=
```

example xor decode

```
perl -e ' $k="flock"; use MIME::Base64; $a=decode_base64("Bw4MY2s="); print $a ^ $k'
abc
```

base36 works on numbers and gives strings so you could use a similar scheme on these.  The output may not be printable however

```
perl -e 'use Math::Base36 qw/:all/; $k=encode_base36(35); $m=encode_base36(10); print ($m ^ $k)'
```

To make this work you'll have to install the CPAN module "Math::Base36".  This is available on ubuntu 12.04 as "libmath-base36-perl"